# Working across sub-lists with apply() functions

Tags: r, apply, nested-lists, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to the bootstrap the proportional occurrence of diet items for 7 individuals and calculate a `sd()`

Lets say there are 9 prey items on the menu.

```
Diet <- c("Beaver","Bird", "Bobcat","Coyote", "Deer", "Elk",
    "Porcupine", "Raccoon",   "SmMamm")
```

And that these prey items are eaten by 7 different individuals of the same species

```
Inds <- c("P01", "P02", "P03", "P04", "P05", "P06", "P07")
```

My goal is the bootstrap the proportional occurrence of each diet item for each individual.
The loop below generates five diets for each individual (each diet containing N = 20 feedings)  that were sampled with replacement.  The data are stored as a list of the individuals, each of which contains a list of the sample diets.

```
BootIndDiet <- list()
IndTotboot <- list()
for(i in Inds){
    for(j in 1:5){
        BootIndDiet[[j]] <- prop.table(table(sample(Diet, 20 ,replace = T)))
                        }
            IndTotboot[[i]] <- BootIndDiet
            }
```

Below I have included the first two diets of individual P07 as an example of the loop results

```
$P07
$P07[[1]]

   Beaver      Bird    Bobcat      Deer       Elk 
     0.05      0.15      0.20      0.10      0.15 
Porcupine   Raccoon    SmMamm 
     0.15      0.15      0.05 

$P07[[2]]

   Beaver      Bird    Bobcat    Coyote      Deer 
     0.15      0.10      0.20      0.05      0.05 
      Elk Porcupine   Raccoon    SmMamm 
     0.05      0.20      0.10      0.10
```

I then want to calculate the sd() of the proportional of each species for each individual.  Equivocally, for each individual (P01 - P07) I want the `sd()` of the proportional occurrence of each prey species across the 5 diets.

While my loop above runs, I suspect there is a better way (possibly using the boot() function) that avoids lists...

While I have only included 5 samples (bootstraps) for each individual here, I hope to generate 10000.

Suggestions on a different strategy or how to apply `sd()` across sub-lists is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless memory problems arise you could store your data in a long format "data.frame" with columns -say- [ind, No_diet, prey, prop] and then you could just call `aggregate(prop ~ ind + prey, mydataframe, sd)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try to obtain an array (instead of a nested list) in this way:

```
   IndTotboot <-array(replicate(5*length(Inds),prop.table(table(sample(as.factor(Diet), 20 ,replace = T))),simplify=T), dim=c(length(Diet),5,length(Inds)), dimnames=list(Diet,NULL,Inds))
```

With `replicate` you can execute an expression a given number of times and store the result as an array (if possible). I added an `as.factor` before `Diet` to make sure that the table takes trace of every Diet (even the ones with a 0 frequency).

The `IndTotboot` object obtained is a 3-dimensional array where the first index indicates the `Diet`, the second the bootstrap replications and the third the `Inds`. From there you can use `apply` in the standard way.

Edit:

If you try `str(IndTotboot)` you get:

```
    > str(IndTotboot)
     num [1:9, 1:5, 1:7] 0.1 0.15 0.15 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.15 0.05 0.1 0.15 ...
     - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
       ..$ : chr [1:9] "Beaver" "Bird" "Bobcat" "Coyote" ...
       ..$ : NULL
       ..$ : chr [1:7] "P01" "P02" "P03" "P04" ...
```

The first line is the most important. It says `num [1:9, 1:5, 1:7]`, which means a 9x5x7 array. The rest indicates the `dimnames`, the names of the dimensions, which is a list. They are the generalization of the `rownames` and the `colnames` for a matrix.

Now, to obtain the `sd` for every `Diet` and `Inds` you just use `apply`:

```
    apply(IndTotboot,MARGIN=c(1,3),sd)
```

Comment: Cool thoughts @nicola, although I cannot get the code for apply().  The str() of the IndTotboot objest says list, but the results from lapply(IndTotboot, sd) are clearly not correct.  What am I missing...?

Comment: `IndTotboot` is an array, not a list. I'm going to expand my answer to show how to use apply.

Answer (score 0):

Following may be useful:

```
dd = data.frame(sapply(IndTotboot, function(x)x))

maindf = data.frame(Var1=as.character(), Freq=as.numeric())

for(rr in 1:nrow(dd)) for (cc in 1:ncol(dd)){
        maindf= merge(maindf, data.frame(dd[rr,cc]), all=TRUE)
}

> head(maindf, 10)
     Var1 Freq
1  Beaver 0.05
2  Beaver 0.10
3  Beaver 0.15
4  Beaver 0.20
5  Beaver 0.30
6    Bird 0.05
7    Bird 0.10
8    Bird 0.15
9    Bird 0.20
10   Bird 0.25


with(maindf, tapply(Freq, Var1, sd))
    Beaver       Bird     Bobcat     Coyote        Elk  Porcupine    Raccoon     SmMamm       Deer 
0.09617692 0.09354143 0.09354143 0.09354143 0.09354143 0.06454972 0.07905694 0.10801234 0.07905694
```

For each individual:

```
counter=1
for (cc in 1:ncol(dd)){
    maindf = data.frame(Var1=as.character(), Freq=as.numeric())
    for(rr in 1:nrow(dd)){
        maindf= merge(maindf, data.frame(dd[rr,cc]), all=TRUE)
    }
    cat("\nFor individual number: ",counter,"\n"); counter=counter+1
    print(with(maindf, tapply(Freq, Var1, sd)))
}


For individual number:  1 
    Beaver       Bird     Bobcat     Coyote        Elk  Porcupine    Raccoon     SmMamm       Deer 
0.05000000 0.07637626 0.05000000 0.06454972 0.03535534 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.07637626 0.05000000 

For individual number:  2 
    Beaver       Bird     Bobcat     Coyote       Deer        Elk  Porcupine    Raccoon     SmMamm 
0.05000000 0.10801234 0.03535534 0.05000000 0.09128709         NA 0.03535534 0.07637626 0.13149778 

For individual number:  3 
    Beaver       Bird     Bobcat     Coyote       Deer        Elk  Porcupine    Raccoon     SmMamm 
0.03535534 0.07637626 0.12583057 0.03535534 0.03535534 0.06454972 0.05000000 0.10606602 0.06454972 

For individual number:  4 
    Beaver       Bird     Bobcat     Coyote       Deer        Elk  Porcupine    Raccoon     SmMamm 
0.05000000 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.03535534 0.10408330 0.07905694 0.05000000 0.03535534 0.10408330 

For individual number:  5 
    Beaver       Bird     Bobcat     Coyote       Deer        Elk  Porcupine    Raccoon     SmMamm 
0.05000000 0.03535534 0.05000000 0.03535534 0.03535534 0.03535534 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.07071068 

For individual number:  6 
    Beaver     Coyote       Deer        Elk  Porcupine    Raccoon     SmMamm     Bobcat       Bird 
0.10000000 0.07637626 0.03535534 0.05000000 0.07071068 0.03535534 0.05000000 0.10408330 0.10606602 

For individual number:  7 
    Beaver       Bird     Bobcat     Coyote       Deer        Elk  Porcupine    Raccoon     SmMamm 
0.03535534 0.05000000 0.10408330 0.07637626 0.05000000 0.13228757 0.07637626 0.03535534 0.05000000
```

For individual+species:

```
maindf = data.frame(Var1=as.character(), Freq=as.numeric(), ind=as.numeric())
counter=1
for (cc in 1:ncol(dd)){
    for(rr in 1:nrow(dd)){
        maindf= merge(maindf, cbind(data.frame(dd[rr,cc]),ind=counter), all=TRUE)
    }
    counter=counter+1
}
with(maindf, tapply(Freq, list(Var1,ind), sd))

                   1          2          3          4          5          6          7
Beaver    0.05000000 0.05000000 0.03535534 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.10000000 0.03535534
Bird      0.07637626 0.10801234 0.07637626 0.05000000 0.03535534 0.10606602 0.05000000
Bobcat    0.05000000 0.03535534 0.12583057 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.10408330 0.10408330
Coyote    0.06454972 0.05000000 0.03535534 0.03535534 0.03535534 0.07637626 0.07637626
Elk       0.03535534         NA 0.06454972 0.07905694 0.03535534 0.05000000 0.13228757
Porcupine 0.05000000 0.03535534 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.05000000 0.07071068 0.07637626
Raccoon   0.05000000 0.07637626 0.10606602 0.03535534 0.05000000 0.03535534 0.03535534
SmMamm    0.07637626 0.13149778 0.06454972 0.10408330 0.07071068 0.05000000 0.05000000
Deer      0.05000000 0.09128709 0.03535534 0.10408330 0.03535534 0.03535534 0.05000000
```